# How to use goToSlide method in react-native-app-intro-slider?

Tags: react-native

I use library react-native-app-intro-slider

I make custom renderPagination, but I can't use goToSlide method in library.

I've already tried custom Pagination Login Signup Buttons, but I can't use too.

This is my code:

```
const _renderPagination = (activeIndex) => {
return (
  <View style={style.paginationContainer}>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={style.paginationDots}>
        {slides.length > 1 &&
          slides.map((_, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={i}
              style={[
                style.dot,
                i === activeIndex
                  ? {backgroundColor: '#9948fc'}
                  : {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)'},
              ]}
            onPress={() => goToSlide(activeIndex, true)} //Error
            />
          ))}
      </View>
      {activeIndex === slides.length - 1 ? (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: '#9948fc'}]}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('signup')}
            >
            <Text style={style.buttonText}>회원가입</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]}
            onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('signup', {log:1})}>
            <Text style={[style.buttonText, {color: '#707070'}]}>
              로그인
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]}
          ><Text style={style.buttonText}/></TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]}
            onPress={() => goToSlide(activeIndex+1, true)}
            >
            <Text style={[style.buttonText, {color: '#707070'}]}>
              다음
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  </View>
);
```

};

Comment: Have you tried to use just number(0,1,2...) instead `"activeIndex"` in `goToSlide()` to check if it works? Or is there any error code?

Comment: Yes.. i'll tried to use number `goToSlide(1, true)` , and have error code **Cannot find name goToSlide**. in my console haver error code **Can't find variable: goToSlide**...

Comment: Have you `import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';` ?

Comment: Yes!  I'll already  `import AppIntroSlider`. Do I have to import other contents?

Comment: I have update an answer, take it a try?

Comment: I declar `const slider : AppIntroSlider | undefinded` there is error code **'const declarations must be initialized** 
I'm using fc Is that so?

Comment: That declare is in example code, not your code...  You don't have to declare it. Have you try my answer? Just use `this.slider = ref` should be declare.

Comment: Or is there face some new problems?

Comment: Sure! i've got error code **this implecity has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotiation**.  and above code has error code **Cannot find name 'slider'... XP

Comment: Where is the error line from? `this.slider = ref` or `this.slider?.goToSlide(i, true)` ? And could you try my update code again, please. I remove the "!" and "?" in those line that make me weird.

Comment: Both code has error from ... Maybe classComponent and Function Comonent has different methods of use. so i searching useRef now.. I hope this search is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I just think that a few minutes ago, but I'm not good at Function Component, but this direction should be correct. Because you have to use his reference to control his method. Sorry couldn't help you more.

Comment: HaHa! Thx for answer my question! XD. It was very helpfulllllll!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems is :

1. You have to set your reference from your `AppIntroSlider Tag` like:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <AppIntroSlider
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          renderPagination={this._renderPagination}
          data={data}
          ref={(ref) => (this.slider = ref)} //Here~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

2. So that you could call `goToSlide()` like this:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
  key={i}
  style={[
    styles.dot,
    i === activeIndex
      ? {backgroundColor: 'white'}
      : {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)'},
  ]}
  onPress={() => this.slider.goToSlide(i, true)}  //Here~~~~~~~~!!!  From the reference
/>
```

[DOC example](https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider/blob/e9fe44504583fe4e2f0bef948ecf4938158d2089/examples/examples/CustomPagination/index.tsx)

Comment: Could someone convert it to functional component?

Answer (score 6):

i just want to add the solution in functional component. This works for me:

```
const slider = useRef();

return(
    <AppIntroSlider
      renderItem={renderItem}
      data={slides}
      onDone={onDone}
      showNextButton={true}
      ref={(ref) => (slider.current = ref)} // the ref
    />
  );

onPress={() => slider.current.goToSlide(1, true)}
```